# How to use Style.Triggers in Silverlight 4.0?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Having switched from WPF to Silverlight 4.0 I am stuck at something quite basic. There seem to be no way I could use a Trigger within my styles.  How is this gonna work?

e.g. here I have created a DataGrid ColumnHeader style within my ResourceDictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader"  >
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#88800080" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridHeaderBackgroundBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="Transparent" />
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderMouseOverBackgroundBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderBorderBrush}" />
            </MultiTrigger>
...
```

Some google search attempts from early 2009 claim to use Converters instead, but I am completely stuck with this. I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hint about how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expression Blend added some support for WPF type Triggers to Silverlight. This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2009/03/30/behaviors-under-the-hood-api-details-and-constraining-the-type.aspx) explains this more.

But in short, you don't get the same value precedence with those triggers as you do with WPF. Meaning, a Style trigger can override a setting made explicitly on an element.

Silverlight uses the [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) concept to "theme" or customize the look of a control. It effectively forces you to define "fixed" states, such as Hover (i.e. IsMouseOver = true) or Pressed. You can then apply animations when entering or exiting these states. So you can say, animate the background brush when hovering to give a hovered look.

The VisualStateManager approach makes it much easier to provide tooling around customizing the look of a control. This is shown in more detail in this [blog post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/06/04/silverlight-introduces-visual-state-manager-vsm.aspx).

So in short, you won't be able to translate it one-to-one. You'll find there are many things like this. For example, there is no IsMouseOver property on UIElement as there is in WPF.

Comment: @Kave - Basically, yeah :-) The first link shows some work-arounds for simple things, but overall VSM isn't as much fun as triggers.

Comment: WoW thats madness. Triggers are a huge part of WPF. Can't imagine being without them :) But I have no choice than to adept